# Dynamic variables - How can I get as name and value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create dynamic variables and I need to get name and value this.

My Code:

```
console.log(listaY)

$.each(listaY, function(key,val){
    console.log(eval(val.nodeName + "Prop" + "= val.nodeValue"));
    console.log(eval(val.nodeName+"Prop").nodeName);
    console.log(key + ":" + val);
});
```

Console:

```
 Object {window: Object}
  window: Object
    childrens: Array[1]
      0: Object
        name: Object
        height: "height"
      __proto__: Object
    __proto__: Object
    length: 1
    __proto__: Array[0]
    height: "auto"
    nome: "Win2"
    width: "auto"
  __proto__: Object
__proto__: Object

view

undefined

0:[object Attr]
```

**listaY is that DOM object**

I need to get the name of the variable and its value from the name.
How I can get this?

**Solution:**

```
var obj = {}; 
$.each(listaY,function(key,val){ 
    obj[val.nodeName + "Prop"] =  val.nodeValue; 
});
```

by: @Rocket Hazmat

Comment: I just don't understand what you are looking for, console.log(key+":"+val); or what?

Comment: you mean you want to end to something like this? `listaY["name"] = "view"` ????

Comment: `listaY = [name="view", height="40"]` is a syntax error.

Comment: Not a syntax error, but it's certainly won't produce what the OP is looking for. It creates two global vars and puts their values in the array.

Comment: @bfavaretto It's not a syntax error. It's valid code.

Comment: What's the question here?  What are you trying to do?  What is `listaY` and what do you want to do with it?

Comment: Probably, `listaY` is that DOM object

Comment: @user2403131, "...name of the variable..." name of which variable?

Comment: Yeah, listY is that DOM object

Comment: @user2403131, it's a bit hard to understand what exactly you're trying to achieve, but if you mange to create an example on http://jsfiddle.net/ , it would be much easier;

Comment: @user2403131: What do you mean by "that DOM object"?  What DOM object?

Comment: @RocketHazmat, the properties of which are displayed in console output?..

Comment: How is `listaY` being created?

Comment: i need create dynamics variables from the DOM object and i get name and value of variable

Comment: `var obj = {};  $.each(listaY,function(key,val){ obj[val.nodeName + "Prop"] = val.nodeValue; });`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Thank you my friend, its working perfectly!!! thank you very much!! :DDDDD

Comment: @user2403131, accept the answer, you do not need to edit your question in order to show the correct answer ;)

Comment: I can't accept resp, but i set solution in post.. thanks to all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `eval`, try setting the values of an object.

```
var obj = {};
$.each(listaY,function(key,val){
    obj[val.nodeName + "Prop"] = val.nodeValue;
});
```